# How to create XElement representing date in DateTime as type xs:Date

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I'm using XDocument to create an XML file, as follows:

```
var d = DateTime.Now;

var xDocument = new XDocument(new XElement("ThisIsADate", d));
```

However, the resulting XML represents the date d using the xs:datetime format (e.g. "2012-05-11T00:00:00"). That is, it includes time information.

However, my XML is meant to match my XML Schema, which defines the element as being of type "xs:date". Consequently, the file is rejected when validated against the schema, because of the extra time information.

How can I fix this? I know I could just format the date myself using ToString() with a format, but this can't be the "right" way to do it, surely. I can't be expected to know how to format a date as a valid XML date - that's the job of the XML-related parts of the framework.

---

**Edit**: please note that I *do* know how to format a date using ToString(), and I also know what format string would give me the right result. That's not the answer I'm looking for. I'm looking for a function/method/class that understands what an xs:date (etc.) is, and that supports those kinds of encodings.

To be clear, I'm not looking to "get it done", I'm looking to "do it right". And re-inventing the XML wheel is not "doing it right" in my book.

Comment: I believe you would need to specify the format using `ToString()` else its just converting the object you pass to its string variant by the `.ToString()` so you will have to pass in the custom format

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it already has been pointed out LINQ to XML is unable to produce a `DateTime` value using the the `xs:date` format. A `DateTime` round-trips in LINQ to XML using the `xs:dateTime` format and .NET does not a have a date-only type so it is not a suprise that the designers of LINQ to XML decided to only use `xs:dateTime` to not complicate the API.

The only option is to format the date as a string giving you full control of the format. To correctly use the `xs:date` format you need to convert the `DateTime` to a string using this code:

```
d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Using `ToShortDateString` and/or not specifying a `CultureInfo` will not produce the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this problem using the following class for DateElements

```
private class XDateElement : XElement
{
   public XDateElement(XName name, DateTime Date) : 
     base(name, Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
   { }
}
```

The advantage of using a class like this is, that you have the specific date conversion only in one place.

```
var d = DateTime.Now;
var xDocument = new XDocument(new XDateElement("ThisIsADate", d));
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some confusion XML or as such the XElement will be storing the Value as a string. What is stored is more a work of the Xml Schema Validator.

Hence when you have to represent `Date` you will have to pass in the string version of the Date part you can use the `ToShortDateString()` or custom format in `ToString()`.

When you are passing the DateTime instance its just calling the ToString() which contains the Time component too.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I understand that the XElement stores a string. My question is, though, how to create the string without resorting to a hard-coded format string. There must be a function within the X... namespace to do this for me?

Answer (score -1):

A `DateTime` *always* has both date and time components. So the trick is tell that `DateTime` to output only it's date component. When you reconstitute the date on the receiving end, the time will default to midnight.

```
var XDocument = new XDocument(new XElement("ThisIsADate", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()));
```

The default form is `M/d/yyyy`, but it still may not be in the right format! I don't know what your schema expects.

So use `ToString("yourFormatStringHere")`

```
var XDocument = new XDocument(new XElement("ThisIsADate", DateTime.Now.ToString("M-dd-yyyy")));
```

If you want to get really fancy, that is, write robust code... Pull the format string from your schema document and reference that in the `ToString()` method rather than having an explicit but redundant format string.

Comment: Thanks, but as I "said" to V4Vendetta, I don't think it's appropriate for me to have to know how to correctly format an XML date. I mean, I *do* know how (yyyy-MM-dd), but I don't think that an XML-creation API is complete without having a function to do this. So I'm pretty confident that there will be a function to do this somewhere - and my question is merely "where?".

Comment: And for the record, the form of an xs:date is not defined by my schema, but by the W3C :-)

Comment: Perhaps `XmlReader.ReadAsDateTime()` will do. By default this attempts DateTime(ing) according to W3C rules.

Comment: I presume you mean ReadContentAsDateTime() or ReadElementContentAsDateTime(). However, I think you're forgetting that I'm trying to *create*, not *read* the XML file.

Comment: `xs:date` is a well defined format: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#date `yyyy-MM-dd` and `yyy-MM-ddzzz` .net format strings both work with it. None of your suggestions match.